# Get parent directory and modification date from a file using Powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I'm looking into building a script that will get me both a date and parent directory of files created during a certain period.
So far this is what I've come up with:

```
get-childitem –recurse | where-object {($_.lastwritetime -gt “7/1/2013”) -and ($_.lastwritetime -le “7/22/2013”) }
```

I'm a bit clueless as to how to separate "Directory" and "LastWriteTime" (minus the time) into variables.

Would appreciate the help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't put them into separate variables. I'd just `select` the 2 properties:

```
$files = Get-ChildItem –Recurse | ? {
  -not $_.PSIsContainer -and
  $_.LastWriteTime -gt "7/1/2013" -and
  $_.LastWriteTime -le "7/22/2013"
} | select Directory, @{n='LastWriteDate';e={Get-Date -uformat "%m\/%d\/%Y"}}
```

Then you can access those values like this:

```
$files[0].Directory.FullName
$files[0].LastWriteDate
```